# Finding free resolution of module.

Tags: homological-algebra

Let $A= \mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2)$ and define the module $M$ by $M=A/(x)$. I am supposed to compute $\text{Ext}_{A}^n(M,A)$. First we start by finding a free resolution for $M$ by $$\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2) \to A/(x) \to 0$$ where the first arrow is just the natural surjection. Now I am really confused in computing $\text{Ext}_{A}^n(M,A)$, because we obtain the complex $$0 \to \text{Hom}_A(\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2),\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2)) \to ...$$

The definition of $\text{Ext}_{A}^n(M,A)$ doesn't even allow me to compute anything here! There is only one arrow in the complex, what have I done wrong? Isn't my free resolution correct?

Comment: You have computed only the first term of a free resolution. You need to find the other terms (up to $n+1$ term at least).

Comment: @Krish in the definition there is no restriction on the length of a free resolution, would $(x)/(x^2) \to \mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2) \to A/(x) \to 0$ serve as a free resolution?

Comment: How do you prove the existence of free resolution of a module? Use the same technique here.

Comment: @Krish Sorry to say that I haven't come to that part of the book, but I will take a look at it. However, is the free resolution I gave above correct? It lets me compute $\text{Ext}_{A}^n(M,A)$, but its only one computation.

Comment: This is not a free resolution. This only a part of a free resolution. Free resolution can be of infinite length. See [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_(algebra))

Comment: @Krish i totally see my mistake now, thank you!

Comment: @Krish I have read through the way you construct free resolutions, if a module $M$ is finitely generated with generating set $X$, we may consider the free module $F_0$ on the set $X$, from here we keep constructing the components of the resolution by considering the kernel of $F_0 \to M$ and so on. I get the resolution $0 \to A/(x) \to A/(x) \to 0$ where the first $A/(x)$ is the free module. Although I feel that I have done something wrong here...would you help me out to understand?

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2259691/what-is-a-projective-resolution-of-mathbbz-m-mathbbz-as-a-mathbbz-n-m), [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2363228/constructing-a-projective-resolution) will help you to understand the idea. Also search for "free resolution" in this site, you will get more examples.